# Sum up the time values corresponding to same date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my sheet column A is date and column B is time duration values, I want to find the dates which are repeated and sum up the corresponding time values of the repeated dates and show the sum in the last relevant repeated date. And delete all the other repeated dates. ie if 18/07/2019 is repeated 4 times i have to sum up all the four duration values and display the sum value in the 4th repeated position and delete the first three date 18/07/2019. I have to do this all those dates that are repeated. I have wrote code to my best knowledge

```
function countDate() {
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = data.getSheetByName("Sheet5");
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
var sh = sheet.getRange('A1:A'+lastRow);
var cell = sh.getValues();
var data= sheet.getRange('B1:B'+lastRow).getValues();
for (var i =0; i < lastRow; ++i){
var count = 0;
var column2 = cell[i][0];

 for (var j =0; j < i; j++)
   {
   var p=0;
   var column4 = cell[j][0]; 
     if (column4 - column2 === 0  )
       {
    var value1 = data[j][0];
    var value2 = data[i][0];
    var d = value2;
    d.setHours(value1.getHours()+value2.getHours()+0);
    d.setMinutes(value1.getMinutes()+value2.getMinutes());
    sheet.getRange('C'+(i+1)).setValue(d).setNumberFormat("[hh]:mm:ss");
    sheet.deleteRow(j+1-p);
    p++; 
       }  
    }
     }   
    }
```

The copy of the sheet is shown
[image]

column C is the values I obtain through the above code AND column D is the desired value

After computing the sum I need to delete the repeated rows till 15 here

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can do this by converting your B-column to a `Plain text` format and doing some data handling with a JavaScript dictionary.*

#### Code:

```js
function sumThemAllUp() {
  var dict = {};
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getLastRow();
  var dates = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A1:A' + lastRow).getValues();
  var times = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('B1:B' + lastRow).getValues();
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).setNumberFormat("@");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    if (!dict[dates[i][0]]) {
      dict[dates[i][0]] = times[i][0];
    }
    else {
      var temp = dict[dates[i][0]];
      var hours = parseInt(temp.split(':')[0]);
      var minutes = parseInt(temp.split(':')[1]);
      var additionalHours = parseInt(times[i][0].split(':')[0]);
      var additionalMinutes = parseInt(times[i][0].split(':')[1]);
      var newMinutes = minutes + additionalMinutes;
      var newHours = hours + additionalHours;
      if (newMinutes > 60) {
        newHours = newHours + 1;
        newMinutes = newMinutes - 60;
      }
      dict[dates[i][0]] = newHours + ':' + newMinutes;
    }
  }
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('A1:B' + lastRow).clear();
  
  var keys = Object.keys(dict);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('A' + (i + 1)).setValue(keys[i]);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('B' + (i + 1)).setValue(dict[keys[i]]);
  }
}
```

#### Assumptions I made:

There are a few assumptions I made when writing this, you can edit as needed but I figured I should let you know:

- There are only dates in Column A and only times in Column B.
- The times in column B are either Hours:Minutes or Minutes:Seconds. Either way, if the value to the right of the `:` hits 60, it adds one to the left value and resets.
- The Sheet within the Spreadsheet is the first sheet; that which is returned by `Spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]`.

#### References:

- [w3schools - JavaScript Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)
- [`Spreadsheet.getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getsheets)
- [w3schools - JavaScript String `split()` Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [MDN web docs - `parseInt()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [Google Sheets > API v4 - Date and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)

Comment: while running the i got an error "Cannot find function split in object Sat Dec 30 1899 01:58:50 GMT+0530 (IST)." corresponding to this line  "var hours = parseInt(temp.split(':')[0]);"

Comment: Make sure to select column B, and follow the menu path `Format > Number > Plain text` before running the script.

Comment: this is a part of a full program, column b is a result of a program when I run on another sheet. Then I write code  for this sheet.So is it possible to convert the format to plain text automatically

Comment: Absolutely! You can implement the [`setNumberFormat("@")`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)) method of the `Range` class to set the number format automatically to a given range. The Date and Number Formats for Sheets can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) but for plain text all you need is `"@"`.

Comment: I wrote as times.setNumberFormat("@"); But now I am getting Cannot find function setNumberFormat in object START TIME,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.

Comment: You need to set the Number format on the range object returned from a `getRange()` method, not the values array. I've updated my code to turn all cells in the sheet into plain text.

Comment: I am still getting error "Cannot convert function getLastRow() {/* */} to (class). " after updating the code ie 
         var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
         sheet.getRange(1, 1, 
            sheet.getLastRow,sheet.getLastColumn).setNumberFormat("@");

Comment: It is a method and needs parentheses, please try the code now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205528/discussion-between-kumara-guru-and-rafa-guillermo).